# MySQL Fabric: ошибка при создании группы

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, при выполнении команды `mysqlfabric group create test` возникает следующая ошибка:

> HTTP Error 403: Not allowed to execute 'core.group.create'

Команда `mysqlfabric manage setup` завершилась успешно, все таблицы созданы, но вот с создание группы трудности, есть у кого мнение как решить данную проблему?